# How to resolve java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, android, connection

i am running my android application in device its not connecting to device.Its giving following error `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` .

EDIT: exception pasted from comment:

```
[2013-12-03 11:02:57 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:03:52 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:04:19 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:07:37 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:10:43 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:11:20 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:14:59 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception and the code around it please?

Comment: Are trying to access http://localhost:8080 like this?

Comment: Add this  if you forget to add to your manifest                       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Failed to install xxx.apk on device 'YT91073S0L': Connection refused: connect
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 Launch canceled!

Comment: Please add some code snap

Comment: i have added then also its not running in device.

Comment: which type of code i should add ? application not running on device.

Comment: I mean post code snap here so that we can see what's problem!

Comment: [2013-12-03 11:02:57 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:03:52 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:04:19 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:07:37 - Device] Error during Sync: Connection refused: connect
[2013-12-03 11:10:43 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:11:20 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L
[2013-12-03 11:14:59 - DeviceMonitor] Failed to start monitoring YT91073S0L

Comment: @amita Is this problem solved?

Comment: no,i think evice is not connectin properly .

Comment: @amita You can see for yourself that exceptions in comments are illegible. I've pasted it into your question where you should have put it yourself in the first place.

Comment: this issue about your device do not connect properly, check your USB cable, mobile device port or restart your eclipse.

Comment: @SatishKumar Not one of those conditions would cause 'connection refused', and there's no evidence that he's using Eclipse at all.

Comment: my problem is solved i have ended the adb process in taskmanager.

Comment: "my problem is solved i have ended the adb process in taskmanager"
This is the solution for the above problem, its not the coding problem its the ADB problem...ADB process goes in a loop and does not respond accordingly..hence killing adb process is the only solution so far...thanks amita for saving my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have INTERNET permission

Comment: i have give internet permission also .